Memory space increases each time a python ipyleaflet map is saved
I noticed a weird behaviour when creating maps with ipyleaflet. Every time I create an ipyleaflet map and want to save it as an html file the resulting file gets iteratively bigger and bigger in space. As I am running something similiar in a for loop the files need consequently a huge amount memory space. I attached a simple script to reproduce the problem:
from ipyleaflet import Map, LayersControl, GeoData
from shapely import Point
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame


# Create a dummy GeoDataFrame
points = GeoDataFrame(geometry = [Point(3.01331, 50.97503),
                                  Point(2.67155, 51.13195),
                                  Point(2.81919, 51.18672),
                                  Point(2.81795, 51.18855),
                                  Point(3.13164, 51.02534),
                                  Point(2.74758, 50.79735),
                                  Point(2.64778, 51.10591),
                                  Point(2.63007, 51.09972),
                                  Point(2.66865, 51.07438),
                                  Point(2.74761, 50.72729)],
                      crs = 4326)


# Convert GeoDataFrame to ipyleaflet Geo_Dataframe
points = GeoData(geo_dataframe=points,
                 point_style={'radius': 5, 'fillColor': 'blue','weight': 3},
                 name = 'Points')

# Initialize ipyleaflet map                 
m = Map(center=(50.95350377279631, 2.8110499565836227), zoom=10)

m.layout.width = '50%'
m.layout.height = '700px'
m.add_control(LayersControl(position="topright"))

# Add Geo_Dataframe to map
m.add_layer(points)


# Save as html
m.save("Map.html")

I already tried to rewrite it as a function and to use the garbage collector (m = None, gc.collect()), but with no success.
